# Java thread run

Tags: java

I have code like this

```
  boolean start = false;
  ThreadX a = new ThreadX();
  a.start();
  start = true;

  Class ThreadX extends Thread {

          public void run() {
              while (start == true) {
                ...
              }

          } 
  }
```

Is there a problem with this code? I have executed this and did not see any issue just wanted to get a hang whether the thread will start and never execute start = true

Comment: replace `extend Thread` with `extends Runnable`

Comment: @Eng: you mean `implements Runnable`.

Comment: and also @Eng, Thread already implements Runnable, so OP is fine in that regard, but there are other issues (e.g. start should be volatile).

Comment: It would be easier to give a good answer if your code would actually be correct Java...

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems:

- Firstly the thread could in theory start before `start` is ever set to true, and thus terminate immediately.
- Secondly the thread could in theory start after `start` is set to true, but never set the value of `start` change (assuming it's being set to false somewhere in the original thread) due to a lack of memory barriers. Either make the variable volatile, use locks, or use one of the `AtomicXXX` types in java.util.concurrent.atomic, e.g. [`AtomicBoolean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

Also for good practice you should implement `Runnable` instead of extening `Thread` - you don't want to change the fundamental behaviour of a thread, you just want to provide it a task. (The fact you *can* extend thread to do this is a design flaw IMO.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a problem.

Assuming that `start` is a local variable, this code will not even compile, since all local variables that are used in inner classes have to be `final`.

Assuming that `start` is a field of some class. Then the field must be declared `volatile`, otherwise it is not guaranteed that if one thread changes the variable, the other threads will see that change.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if `start` becomes true before or after `run()` begins. I say "it depends" because there is no guarantee by the JVM that either will be the case. This is, of course, assuming that `start` is within scope of the instance of your thread.

Answer (score 0):

with this it is not guaranteed that the loop will ever enter:

if the thread is started and the current thread (the thread starting the other one) is interrupted so the other thread can run the while condition will be false and the run will exit

on the other hand if the current thread is not interrupted and set start to true the loop will enter

this is known as a race condition

Answer (score 0):

The thread will start, but might exit immedietly, exit later, or run forever:

Scenario 1 - run forever
before thread run() enters, start is updated to true and the jvm decides to write it to the memory so the created thread will see it as true and will never terminate.

Scenario 2 - exit immediately 
before run() starts the start is updated to true but the jvm don't update physical memory (no membar), then run continues and sees false, and will terminate, or the run() and the loop runs for the first before start=true is run.

Scenario 3 - exit at some point
before run() or after run() start is updated but the jvm updates the physical memory at some point after run do a number of iterations.